# how to set server variable to javascript src attribute in pug template using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, server, pug

I am integrating `api` with `Node.js` and I have to set `src` attribute of script as server variable.
Here is real code.(what i want to execute)

```
Server side
res.render('sample', {usertoken:'somerandomstring'});

Client side
script(src='https://apibaseurl/'+#{usertoken}+'/en.min.js')
```

The result I want is

```
script(src='https://apibaseurl/somerandomstring/en.min.js')
```

How to do it and what am i wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Define it first:

(Client side)

```
script.
  var usertoken ="#{usertoken}";
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = "https://apibaseurl/" + usertoken + "/en.min.js";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Note that if it is some kind of credentials of private data, it will be accessible via page source.

Answer (score 0):

script(src='https://apibaseurl/'+usertoken+'/en.min.js')